# C++ Error when accessing vector<string> elements through iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, sdl

Relevant code is as follows:

I've tested each Nurse object assignment and the entire thing separately and the data is stored correctly, I'm just not able to access it to determine which tiles to display for some reason. I've also tried accessing the data without an iterator and that didn't work either. Any ideas are thoroughly appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for hours :/

```
for(unsigned int j = 42; j < EntityManager::getInstance()->nurses.size() * 42 + 42; j += 42) //increment y axis
{
    int rosterCounter = 0;
    int count = 0;
    vector<string> roster = EntityManager::getInstance()->nurses[count]->getRosterData();
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;

    iter = roster.begin();

    for(unsigned int i = GraphicsCore::getInstance()->screenWidth; rosterCounter <= EntityManager::getInstance()->getSize() && iter != roster.end(); i -= 64) //iterate through each column, RTL
    {

        TextBox * text;

        if(*iter == "D")
        {
            text = new TextBox("resources/tiles/textboxshortd.png", i, j, (TextBox::type) 4);
        }
        else if(*iter == "N")
        {
            text = new TextBox("resources/tiles/textboxshortn.png", i, j, (TextBox::type) 4);
        }
        else if(*iter == "O")
        {
            text = new TextBox("resources/tiles/textboxshorto.png", i, j, (TextBox::type) 4);
        }
        else
        {
            text = new TextBox("resources/tiles/textboxshort.png", i, j, (TextBox::type) 4);
        }
        iter++;
        rosterCounter++;
    }
    count++;
}
```

**Edit: It now runs but the first iteration seems to do nothing, no tiles are placed at all in the first column for some reason and it appears to be offset entirely by 1. I tried begin()-1 but that didn't work either. Thanks for your help guys :)**

Comment: Updated Question, sorry I should've added that lol

Comment: Just a side note: You should probably be using a smart pointer for `text`.

Comment: Can you get a debugger onto it to find out precisely where it's crashing, and how?

Comment: the `if(iter!=roster.end())` is likely wrong.  You'll want to add that as a condition to the for loop: `; rosterCounter <= EntityManager::getInstance()->getSize() && iter != roster.end(); `.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar begin()-1 is not a good idea! Have you read the C++ Reference for vector? Did you try a simple example? For your own safety, print out the value of the iterator or start debugging your application.

Answer (score 3):

You're never checking your iterator to see whether it's `!= roster.end()`. If it is, it will lead to undefined behavior when you attempt to dereference or increment it.

Also, note that your code most likely leaks. You never `delete text;`.

Comment: I had tried that previously and it didn't make a difference. I'll add it in again now and update.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar you're checking the iterator after you dereference it. Really?

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar if the iterator is `end`, `*iter == "D"` is illegal.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar also, what line do you get the crash at?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore is spot on with this (and see my comment on the question itself re checking the iterator)

Comment: Also, I've noticed that it doesn't cycle between the different rosters, still repeats the same one 4 times...Count is being incremented so I'm not sure what's going on there, they should be different.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar seems logic to me, the count goes not up. You are picking always the roster of nurse 0

Comment: Okay, woops moved int count declaration outside initial for loop now and it cycles but I'm still missing the first tile on the first iteration...Weird

Comment: Actually it's wrapped around, I'm getting the last tile first and then the first one second and so on...

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar you know what? NO!!! Learn how to ask a proper question. Read the FAQ.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar in case it's not clear, it's not OK to completely alter your question. Sure, fix typos, but stick with the same logic. This is basically asking a different question.

Comment: Technically it is but logically it's still the same problem. I'm trying to print out a roster and I can't get it to work. Why bother submitting separate questions for the same problem and I don't expect you to do it all for me, I've spent hours on this and tried so many things and just can't fix it. I just wanted a little help.

Comment: This question itself is a complete chaos, you want us to solve your problem but you seem not even be able to start a debugger and tell us which line it crashes on. That you miss the elementary C++ skills is not an issue but I suggest you start to work structured and acknowledge that the people here are helping you not the other way around.

Comment: I have run a debugger several time it was crashing on the if statement, hence my original post. But whatever, you guys don't seem very tolerable so I'll just figure it out myself.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar well this information is not provided in your post and the answer is simple, if it crashes anywhere near your if statement than you have value which is not initialized or you have iterated over the "edge" of your vector. Now with the hint from Martin you have that safety, we don't even know if it is still crashing or not.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar on the contrary. We are tolerable, that's why the question didn't get closed to start off with. It should have been though, the code is incomplete, it doesn't compile, you didn't tell us where the crash is, there are no object declarations to see what the objects actually are... need I go on?

Answer (score 0):

if you know the size of it

```
vector.size()
```

you can access each element by

```
vector.at(x);
```

If the Entity Manager gives you a copy of the data than this should be ok (i assume it because its not a pointer)

What you maybe have to explain is why you have such cryptic for loops it makes no sense that your first loop starts with 42 in the index variable, i think you are doing two things in one step and that makes your life more difficult.

As you might know you should provide the line it crashes on.

If you first pick the data and after display it, you would probably spot the error by yourself.

Edit: I have realized that you seem not to understand what you are doing, don't just hack around in your code, visualize your problem. In addition, your logic is not clear to me, when you have a vector with 10 elements, why would you try to access element -1 if element 0 will not print out the value you want to see? You should try it the other way around, check why the value at 0 is not containing what you want. I also assume that you haven't written the initial code, try to understand the code first. Get some paper and draw the current work flow and the targeted work flow you are trying to build.

Comment: The 42 thing is for tile placement (40px tile height and 2px spacing between rows) just FYI :) But I guess you are right in that I should do 2 things at once...

Comment: I actually have written the entire thing, it's a ported game engine that I built a year ago.

Comment: @JarrodCabalzar If you have written the entire thing, why don't you know that iter.begin() -1 is a really bad idea? Honestly not even in a beginners class I have ever seen somebody trying to do this and if so only for seeing what happens